# Plone/XDV Related Item Overlay is Empty

Tags: popup, overlay, plone, xdv, diazo

I have a Plone 4 site using collective.xdv for the theme. Overlays for the login and contact form work fine.

But if I go to edit > categorization tab and try to add a related item, the overlay is blank. Looking at it in Firebug, the tags are correct down to div.overlaycontent. But inside of that div is my static HTML from the XDV theme's index.html.

Is there a special rule that I need for the overlays?

I cannot use plone.app.theming because this site is using more than just Plone.

Comment: collective.xdv (which plone.app.theming replaces) is also Plone specific. XDV (the underlying technology) has been renamed Diazo. You can still compile your theme to an XSLT and deploy in Apache / Nginx / WSGI using Diazo. I would recommend migrating to plone.app.theming once you update to Plone 4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xdv configuration(or append "@@xdv-settings" onto site url), you can add unstyled paths.

I think what you'll need is:

```
^.*/referencebrowser_popup(\?.*)?$
```

or

```
^.*refbrowser_popup(\?.*)?$
```

If neither of those work, figure out the url that's being requested and add it as an unstyled path.